# MySQL: Auto increment minus one?

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I have some code that will delete a post from the database:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM `posts` WHERE ID = '$id'");
```

Now I want to set the auto increment minus one to keep up with the deleted post. Is this possible? If so, how can I do it? Thanks!

Comment: That is not how the auto increment is supposed to work. IDs are not supposed to be reused after deletion

Comment: Why? What does it gain you? What happens if the id isn't the maximum id?

Comment: really? should I just let it go, and have the auto increment work by itself?

Comment: Absolutely what Pekka said.  And besides you can't know that the one you are deleting is actually the last one created.

Comment: That's also true! I hadn't thought of that! Thank you!

Comment: Hey, I can't really help it if it's awful. Enlighten me how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really don't want to do this.

Imagine the following happens:

A new post is made with id 100
A new post is made with id 101
A new post is made with id 102
Post 100 is deleted... your post counter is now at 101
A new post is made with id 101

So now you have two ids with 101? If your constraints let you, that's bad. If they don't let you, it's impossible.

Either way, it's best to just let the 'id 101' die forever. It won't be missed, there's a few billion more numbers to pick from...

Answer (score 5):

You can manually set the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html), but that's a bad idea.

First, say there are 5 posts. If the post with ID 3 is deleted, you can't really set the auto-increment to 3 because IDs 4 and 5 are still in use.

Second, if there are any references to that ID in another table that didn't get deleted then those references will be bad when that ID is reused.

In general, auto-increment values are meant to be used once only. You can get around this if you want, but there's really no reason to.

Answer (score 1):

alter table yourtable auto_increment=5

Perhaps a subquery can be used to get the count:

alter table yourtable auto_increment=(select count(*) from yourtable) + 1

Are you really sure this is what you want to do? Remember that this will break if you delete a row "In the middle" and not the last one.

Comment: It looks like subqueries in this specific case does not work, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16673269/change-auto-increment-within-same-table-using-subquery-mysql