# How to maintain continuos auto_increment values in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have 2k rows with current highest auto_increment value being 2000. Now, if i delete, say, 1000 rows from the top (1001 to 2000), the auto_increment still continues from 2001 instead of 1001. This results in needless high values of auto_increment. Is there a way to even "auto-adjust" this?

I tried something like below but it doesn't work

```
ALTER TABLE `updatelogs` AUTO_INCREMENT = (select max(update_id) from updatelogs);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [change auto\_increment within same table using subquery mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16673269/change-auto-increment-within-same-table-using-subquery-mysql) ... You can't do this, but there is no reason for you to be doing this.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be duplicate of that question! 
As for the reason, this will be required if, say, last 1000 rows  of some 2000 rows are deleted... the auto increment will continue from 2001, i want it to continue from 1001!

Comment: My feeling is that you should be letting the MySQL engine handle the auto increment column (keyword: **auto**).

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. Most probably what you are asking isn't what you need.

Comment: @vhu, right! Need to edit the question!

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, that seems to be the solution decided in the other question as well. But, it will result in unnecessary high values of auto_increment...considering MySQL doesn't "auto" arranges them!

Comment: *why* do you need to reset the auto increment? Why does it matter if there are gaps in the primary key? Are you fine with having gaps within the sequence (e.g. you have 2000 rows; rows with IDs 1500-1600 are deleted)? Are you using it for something else than to identify the row, e.g. use IDs order id shown to the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following query to reset the auto increment column after any number of records have been deleted:

```
ALTER TABLE `updatelogs` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

As [this useful SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740358/mysql-reorder-reset-auto-increment-primary-key) describes, this will reset the auto increment column to `MAX(update_id) + 1`.

Comment: Right! I am so sorry... missed this trick. Now, i understand why you earlier said that its unnecessary!